# How to fix Partition Overlapping?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, norton-ghost

I found I somehow have parition overlap (not sure how that happened...I used acronis to it). Now Norton ghost (version 15) won't let me make backups and I am not sure what to really do.

Reading on the Norton Forums I found to check I should use a utlitity they have called "partinfo.exe"

This makes a file called "partinfo.txt" what is quite long so here is the highlight of it.

> .........................................................................................................................
>   System               Part Table LBA   # Boot     BCyl Head Sect FS
>   ECyl Head Sect       StartSect         NumSects
>   ========================================================================================================================= K:\    On Disk Values:                0   0   0       974  231  15  07
>   365  171  27      123,117,575      966,213,625    Calculated:
>   8142  167  15         72045  171  27
>
> WARNING: Partition above overlaps with primary partition # 2.
>
> C:\    On Disk Values:                0   1  80       820  198   7  07
>   353  190  46    1,529,733,120      209,698,816    Calculated:
>   101172  198   7        115041  190  46
>
> WARNING: Partition above overlaps with primary partition # 2.
>
> Extended Partition    On Disk Values:                0   2   0
>   0   32  33  0F       177  135  55            2,048    1,953,517,568
>   Calculated:                                      0   32  33
>   129201    7  55

Comment: what version of Norton Ghost are you using?  What's telling you that there is overlap?  Have you checked the condition of the partition(s) with any (other) partitioning or disk tools?  Did this ever work?  What changed?

Comment: What utility reported that? Some older apps can't handle modern large size drives and incorrectly report errors. Have you taken a look at gparted live to examine/check/fix the partitions?

Comment: No I have not tried gpart. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I suggest http://pastebin.com/ for long text files.